# Binding a key to a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, key-bindings, tkinter-text

I have a problem with binding a key (Ctrl-A) to a function (select all) in menu_bar function. Whatever I do, this key combination is moving me to beginning of the line.

My main program:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import func
from tkinter import font

class Editor():
    def __init__(self, window):
        # Window + Title
        window.geometry('1200x800')
        window.title('SuperEditor')
        # Scrool bar
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        # Text area
        user_font=font.Font(size=20)
        editor = Text(window,width=400,height=450,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, undo = True,
        font=user_font)
        editor.pack(fill=BOTH)
        scrollbar.config(command = editor.yview)

        # Selfs
        self.window = window
        self.editor = editor
        self.user_font = user_font

        editor.bind("<Control-A>", func.select_all(editor))



    def menu_bar(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.window)
        # Edit menu
        editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=lambda: func.select_all(self.editor), accelerator='Ctrl-A')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

        
        # Add the menu bar
        self.window.config(menu=menubar)




def main():
    # Create a SuperEditor window
    se_window = Tk()
    # Create a text editor
    editor = Editor(se_window)
    # Create menubar
    editor.menu_bar()
    # Rune the SuperEditor
    se_window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Functions file:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter import font


def select_all(text, event=None):
    '''Select all text'''
    if event:
        print('Up')
        text.tag_add("sel", "1.0","end")
        text.tag_config("sel",background="gray",foreground="white")
        return 'break'
    else:
        text.tag_add("sel", "1.0","end")
        text.tag_config("sel",background="gray",foreground="white")
```

When I put this in `__init__`, it selects everything at start, but doesn't work later:

```
self.editor.bind("<Control-A>", functions.select_all(editor))
```

I tried to do it with lambda, then i get:

```
TypeError: Editor.menu_bar.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the code you have provided.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the full traceback. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the edit. We'd still like to see the full traceback revealed.

Comment: Change `editor.bind("<Control-A>", func.select_all(editor))` to `editor.bind("<Control-A>", lambda event: func.select_all(editor, event=event))`

Comment: After chaning to 'editor.bind("<Control-A>", lambda event: func.select_all(editor, event=event))', it's not selecting at the start, but Ctrl+A still moves the cursor to the beggining

Comment: @koleks92 Does it call the `select_all` function?

Comment: No, if i checked correctly( i added print statement to the function), it does not call select_all function.

Comment: It works, took me some time to realise that it's capital A in the code, thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Button's command executed immediately when I create the Button, and not when I click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-my-buttons-command-executed-immediately-when-i-create-the-button-and-no)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
editor.bind("<Control-A>", func.select_all(editor))
```

to

```
editor.bind("<Control-A>", lambda event: func.select_all(editor, event=event))
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75017871/8) to the question [Binding a key to a function in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017871/binding-a-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter) by the OP [koleks92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19896584/koleks92) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>